# What audio formats are supported by Azure Cognitive Services' Speech Service (SST)?

Tags: python, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services, pydub

Bearing in mind that the Microsoft/Azure Cognitive Services' "Speech Service" is currently going through a rationalisation exercise, as far as I can tell from looking at

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/rest-apis#speech-to-text

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech/home

only `.wav` binaries are acceptable, with anything else giving the response:

```
{"Message":"Unsupported audio format"}
```

Is there any other way to discover the acceptable audio formats/encodings/etc., or is this it?

[Bonus points for tips on preprocessing arbitrary/`.m4a` audio formats in python `pydub` so that they meet the bar - currently works for `.mp3` but not for `.m4a`].

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The currently support format is [WAV (16 kHz or 8 kHz, 16-bit, and mono PCM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/speech-service/how-to-use-codec-compressed-audio-input-streams). More format and codec support will be added in future.